# Jenkins error al instalar plugins

Tags: java, deployment, jenkins

Tengo un problema instalando plugins en Jenkins, cuando selecciono un plugin y le doy a instalar aparece este error:

```
java.io.IOException: Downloaded file C:\Users\informatica\.jenkins\plugins\jdk-tool.jpi.tmp does not match expected SHA-1, expected 'K+QyfQDLMux19gZgQJSwtmwB2PY=', actual 'gU+ah3D/JBUdNqbvXwlRp8NB0NQ='
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.verifyChecksums(UpdateCenter.java:1810)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.access$1100(UpdateCenter.java:149)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob.replace(UpdateCenter.java:1963)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.install(UpdateCenter.java:1194)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1680)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1874)
at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1651)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Tengo instalado jenkins en un servidor con wndows 10. Y lanzo el jenkins con java -jar jenkins.war

Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser algo tan sencillo como reiniciar el servicio de Jenkins:

Algunos de los comandos:

**Detener:**    `jenkins.exe stop`

**Iniciar:**  `jenkins.exe start`

**Reiniciar:** `jenkins.exe restart`

Luego de realizar un cambio de configuración, recuerda realizar un respaldo  de todos los archivos que tengas a la fecha.

Saludos